# Add new element to list using for

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I do not know how best to solve this in elixir but given a number to make print its sequence like this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`:

```
n = 10
list = []
for i <- 0..n - 1, do: list = list ++ [i]
IO.inspect list
```

This code above returns me this:

```
warning: variable "list" is unused
    solution.ex:8

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Solution.main/0 is undefined or private
    Solution.main()
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:677: Code.require_file/2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Elixir's variables are scoped to the "block" that they are in. Lets see what that looks like with your code.

```
n = 10
outer_list = []
for i <- 0..n - 1, do: inner_list = outer_list ++ [i]
IO.inspect outer_list
```

So the value of `inner_list` will always be `[] ++ [i]` because `outer_list` is not being changed. When you named both `inner_list` and `outer_list` to just `list`, you are shadowing the variable. Meaning it has the same name, but different value based on the scope. You are also getting a warning stating that `inner_list` is not actually used anywhere.

What you probably want to do is

```
n = 10
list = for i <- 0..n - 1, do: i
IO.inspect list
```

Though, you may be better served using [`Enum.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#to_list/1).

```
n = 10
list = Enum.to_list(0..n-1)
IO.inspect list
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using [list comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html#generators-and-filters) like:

```
list = for i <- 0..(n - 1) do i end
IO.inspect list
```

Answer (score 1):

While @neisc gave a good answer, I would rather do:

```
list = list ++ (for i <- 0..(n - 1) do i end)
```

Which add something to the original list while also keeping the data that it might already contain.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add another one to the mix.

The classic `Enum.map/2`

```
n = 10
list = Enum.map(0..n-1, &(&1))
IO.inspect list
```

Not quite as concise as `Enum.to_list/1` but a little more versatile.